# Undoing calendar sync between iPhone and Outlook

Tags: data-synchronization, ms-office, iphone

I was trying to save the calendar data on my iPhone to my Outlook calendar. I connected via iTunes and the sync caused all my iPhone calendar data to disappear, overwriting it with the data from the Outlook calendar. How can I restore my iPhone calendar data?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! To help others help you, you should try to provide as many details as possible pertinent to your question. In this case, it would be helpful to know on which platform you have been syncing (both Outlook and iTunes exist on OS X and Windows), which iOS version you are running and which kind of calendar data you had on the iPhone before syncing (iCloud, Exchange, Google, local?).

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to restore your Calendar from a previous back-up in iTunes.
Check the time and date of the previous back-ups.
Windows: Edit > Preferences > Devices tab
Mac: iTunes > Preferences > Devices tab

Restore from your back-up and see if your events come back. Restore by right-clicking (Option+click on a Mac) on the device and selecting "Restore from back-up"

The best way to sync with Outlook would be to download the iCloud Control Panel. This lowers your risk of losing Calendar data, as in your case. Of course, you need to have iCloud enabled on your device as well. This requires iOS 5 or later.
You can check this under: Settings > iCloud
You can download the iCloud Control Panel here: http://apple.com/icloud/setup

Make sure that when it is installed and you are signing in, that you use the same AppleID that is used with iCloud on your device.

Comment: Hi Angie, Thanks very much. But I am not using a Mac; I'm suing a PC. Is there a comparable option for the PC?

Comment: The iCloud Control Panel can be installed on a PC.

Comment: To restore your device, right-click on it, and select "Restore from back-up".

I was just providing information for a Mac as well because I was not sure which you were using. Please try the steps above.

Comment: Windows = PC
Proceed with "Windows" steps.